# display tag table in dialog struts2

Tags: struts2, displaytag

I am using display tag to display a table of records that is opened inside a dialog, but when i click on pagination link , it redirect to anothe page and hide dialog

I need to keep pagination in the same dialog

Thank's in advance.

Comment: That's what links do, they make a new request. While an iframe would actually work, and may fit your actual requirements, in general, iframes aren't an awesome UX. It might be better to fix it with JS.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a iframe in the dialog box and within the iframe you use the displaytag.

JSP with dialog:

```
<sj:dialog>
   <iframe src="path/to/actionwithdisplaytable.action" with="" height="">
   </iframe>
</sj:dialog>
```

JSP with displaytag:

```
<displaytag:...>
   <displaytag:column/>
</displaytag:...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response, the problem is fixed by adding the requestURI, containg the name of myAction.